# Select nth image out of all images which is inside an html element

Tags: jquery, css

Please consider the following html code

```
<div id="maindiv">
<img/>
<p><img/></p>
<p><img/></p>
<div><div><img/></div></div>
<div><img/></div>
<img/>
</div>
```

You can see that there are total 6 img `<img/>` tags inside `<div id="maindiv">` .
I need to select the first (or nth) image which is inside `<div id="maindiv">`

Comment: Are you hunting for general strategy, or some example code within some  language domain?  If the latter, what langauge will you be using? (JavaScript? Java? ...?)

Comment: Select it with what? CSS? JavaScript? jQuery? A magic wand?

Comment: Select and to do what with it?

Comment: user3264864: @JayBlanchard's comment may have ended a tiny bit snarky, but it was a very valid request for additional information. If you think his comment was out of line, you should have flagged it for moderator attention; not called him a name.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$("#maindiv img:eq(1)")
```

Will work. where 1 is the 0 based index.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [**.eq()**](https://api.jquery.com/eq/),

> Reduce the set of matched elements to the one at the specified index.

```
$('#maindiv img').eq(0); // For first
```

*OR*

You can also use the [**:eq()**](http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors/eq) operator.

```
$('#maindiv img:eq(0)'); // For first
```